# Combine Sql Query LIKE OR AND to list product when type is true

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I have been try to select from my table using `LIKE OR AND` sql query.
I want to list all product that the products-type is `bakery-catering`and at the same time using like to get it from matched location. 
But the sql query below is showing all products in the matched location ignoring the product-type that i want.

```
SELECT * FROM productservice  
WHERE product_address LIKE "Enugu-ezike,%" 
OR product_address_two LIKE "ezike district%" 
OR product_description LIKE "cooking%"  
AND product_type = "bakery-catering"
```

This is showing all product type from the searched location. Please how can i fix this?

Comment: Use parentheses to group your logic terms.

Comment: @GyroGearloose, please am new to programming, can you help out in a practical way.

Comment: The "AND" applies only to the previous LIKE. You should do: SELECT * FROM productservice  
WHERE ( product_address LIKE "Enugu-ezike,%" 
OR product_address_two LIKE "ezike district%" 
OR product_description LIKE "cooking%"  )
AND product_type = "bakery-catering" -- note the "(" and the ")", it's just like in math: 5 + 4*3 versus (5 + 4)* 3.

Comment: @GyroGearloose, Looks like the parenthesis isn't added in your suggestion.

Comment: @ArunGeorge it is now, it was a copy&paste mishap

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM productService  
WHERE 
    (
    product_address LIKE 'Enugu-ezike,%'   OR
    product_address_two LIKE 'ezike district%' OR 
    product_description LIKE 'cooking%'
    )  
    AND product_type = 'bakery-catering'
```

OR if you insist to use double quotation marks then,

```
SELECT * FROM productservice  
WHERE
    (
    product_address LIKE "Enugu-ezike,%"  OR 
    product_address_two LIKE "ezike district%" OR 
    product_description LIKE "cooking%"
    )  
    AND product_type = "bakery-catering"
```

Comment: it worked, can you explain to me what the open and close bracket hast to do on that?

Comment: @PhilipJems in the version without grouping, the AND applies only to the last LIKE, here it applies to all the LIKE ... OR ... LIKE ... OR ... LIKE expression.

Comment: yes. Gyro explained it very well. Just all in parenthesis () as one statement. and other parts as another statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM productservice  
WHERE product_type = "bakery-catering"
AND product_address LIKE "Enugu-ezike,%" 
AND product_address_two LIKE "ezike district%" 
AND product_description LIKE "cooking%"
```

if you have 50 rows of product_type = bakery-catering 
if you have 40 rows of product_type = bakery-catering and product_description = "cooking%"
if you have 20 rows of product_type = bakery-catering and product_description = cooking% and product_address_two = "ezike district%"
if you have 10 rows of product_type = bakery-catering and product_description = cooking% and product_address_two = "ezike district%"
and product_address = "Enugu-ezike,%"

then that query will give you only 10 rows of selecting criteria